# 2d gridbased Pathfinding: Cheapest way/algorithm to find out if a location is reachable

Tags: algorithm, 2d, path-finding, a-star

My main pathfinding is done by an implementation of the aStar algorithm. The performance is great as long as there is a path available.

However if there is none, then potentially all available nodes will be parsed until you come to the conclusion that there is no path.

The worst case scenario I can come up with is very few obstacles relatively close to the target-location, surrounding it.

Some ideas I have come up with so far that may increase overall performance:

- find and execute a cheaper pathfinding algorithmn that is run only to find out if the target is reachable, if it is, run aStar to get the actual path.
- gather all unwalkable nodes around the targetnode in a specified radius and see if they are all linked. If they are, the target is 'unreachable' and can't be reached.
  Doing the equivalent for the startnode is not neccessary, as aStars way of gathering nodes essentially does this.

So what I'm asking for here is if there is someone out there that has some bulletpoints/ideas I could add to my list, or point me in the direction of a cheaper pathfinding algorithm that I can utilize to make sure if there is a path

Comment: You should remove some language tags and let only the relevant ones.

Comment: "My main pathfinding is done by an implementation of the aStar algorithm. The performance is great..." Which language is it written in?

Comment: I wrote it in c# then out of curiosity also in c++

Comment: Even if you find a way to quickly determine whether the target is reachable, this won't help your speed when the target *is* reachable but only via an incredibly long (specifically: O(n)-length, where n is the number of vertices) path -- e.g., when source and target are at opposite ends of a long maze.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, I am aware. I believe going with bi-directional is great as it won't impact execution-time at all in most reachable scenarions and has a positive effect in a lot of unreachable cases.

Comment: Bidirectional search will certainly help if (a) the target is unreachable and (b) this is due to obstructions near the target.  It sounds like that is a common scenario, but my point is that you will still have unacceptable running times in the (different) scenario I described, unless you either (a) know that that situation will never occur or (b) come up with a different technique to solve *that* problem (which will, as a byproduct, most likely also solve the problem that bidirectional search solves).

Comment: @j_random_hacker ah now I get your point. Well the scenario of a long maze isn't that bad as #1: For it to be a good maze, around half the nodes aren't walkable and thus aren't iterated over by the pathfinding. #2: If it was a succesful pathsearch, the unit looking for a path wont request another path for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Idea, should be refined!

Because of your Heuristic, A* will spend most of it's time around the target,
therefore creating a "visited" wall around it.

so i think you can check for continues "wall" of visited squares,
if you find a closed, continuous path that contains the target, but not the source, you've got nothing to search further.

Second Idea, not complete, but will probably reduce the "LOST" time,
Use Bi-Directional A*, Source running to Destination, but in the same time Destination finding it's way to the Source.

Take a look at https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/ to get the idea how it will behave.

Comment: oh I like your second idea! If either of the astar instances has no more nodes I can abort both. I believe this halves the worst-case time.Why isn't it complete?

Comment: because, in the worst case it doesn't help at all :) assume a wall crossing in the middle... you will still visit everywhere...

Comment: i got a third angle, for mapping out the "obstecles map", and checking for closed rings containing `Dest XOR Src`

Comment: from your link, if I don't care about the absolute shortest path, what speaks against using bi-directional best-search-first instead of astar? It seems to be a lot faster in the scenarios I tested

Comment: Best-FS is surely a good way to go except for some points where the Heuristics are misleading, but for most cases, it is even a tad faster.
I written A* to match the question.